# How to make kodi as default media player

Tags: sound, video, vlc, music, tv

Kodi player looks better then vlc. because in kodi i can create my own add-ons in python and it is easy to do. so i want to set it default. how to use kodi as default media player it is not default

Comment: I doubt that Kodi is working that way and I guess you have to start the media file within Kodi to play it with Kodi.

Answer (score 2):

Kodi does not seem to be build for launching videos from the outside, but **it is possible**

As from the terminal you can launch a video by running

```
kodi /path/to/video
```

### How to make it the default player :

#### Enable opening a video with KODI

You first have to configure the desktop application to be accept file as 'argument'. You have to edit `/usr/share/applications/kodi.desktop`, one way to do that is to open a terminal and enter :

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/kodi.desktop
```

find the line `Exec=kodi` and add `%f` so that you have

```
Exec=kodi %f
```

To save and exit press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>Y</kbd> and finally <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now you can open a video with a *right-click* > `Open With Other Application` > `View All Applications`.

#### Make it default

To make it default you have to open the *Properties* of a video (*right-click* > `Properties` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) go to the `Open With` section, then select `Kodi` and click `Set as default`.

You will have to do this last action for every file type of video (mp4, avi, mkv, ...).